# Android Source code - How to identify dependencies of particular fiie

Tags: dependencies, libraries, android-build

I am working in porting android source code for blaze board. In that, I have made changes in the files in the following directory.

- /mydroid/frameworks/base/media/libmedia/
- /mydroid/frameworks/base/media/libmediaplayerservice/
- /mydroid/frameworks/base/media/libstagefright/
- /mydroid/frameworks/base/include/media/
- /mydroid/hardware/ti/omap4xxx/libdsswb/

After building, I have pushed the following libraries to blaze board.

1. libmedia.so
2. libmediaplayerservice.so
3. libstagefright.so
4. libdsswb.so

But when I try to push the above libraries to the board, my application is not working. If I build android completely it is working fine.

I know that, my changes affect other libraries also. I want to know that how to identify the libraries which is depended on particular files?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you should care about the changing files' Android.mk, and then you can `mm` in the Android.mk direcotry. And then, you should push all **Install** files.